# M-V-VM: What is the best way to handle model data that is generated dynamically from XmlSerialized data

Tags: c#, mvvm, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged, xmlserializer

I have both, actual user-generated data and data that depends on it (like the background color of UniformGrid cells that is used to indicate dupe values in the grid, which is calculated each time an INotifyPropertyChanged is fired from the grid's ObservableCollection). There are other such objects that are interdependent in the model. Now when deserialized, depending on the order of the objects in the model class, some dependending objects are updated correctly and some are not. (I come from MFC programming and am used to call UpdateData() after loading a file and set all DDX controls at once.)

The whole thing is quite susceptible to getting buggy on subsequent changes in the code and feels very clumsy. It's like many things with WPF: If you want to acomplish an easy task, it's done in no time. If you want something specific, it gets much more complicated than it should. Is there any good practice how to deal with the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your main propblem is the correct separation of concerns. WPF & MVVM is quite different from more traditional methods of Windows development.

First up, let's get something sorted here - it might just be a confusion with the terminology, but I'll mention it.

In MVVM the model is not used to store data.

*Can* it be used to hold data? Yes. 
*Should* it be used to hold data? No.

Holding and transforming the data is the job of the viewmodel. The job of the model is to act as a conduit, it fetches the data (i.e. retrieves from your repository, or controls communication with WCF services, etc). If your model is holding data that means your view will be binding to the model, which is wrong.

Some of the data you talk of should also be held in the view. Determining whether something is a duplicate can be determined in the viewmodel, possibly even in the model (the model could apply business rules and flag data as it passes through). The color to show for the duplicate is a view responsibility - unless that color is determined by business rules, then you can move it to the viewmodel.

You are binding to an ObservableCollection, which infers that you are using a repeater type control like a DataGrid. In this case each row is not aware of any other row. If you fire a property change event from the data object of one row, another row will be totally unaware of it and therefore cannot change how it is rendered based on those changes. In cases like this you must adjust the data of the related row in an observer pattern way.

When you have interdependencies like this, it is normal to wrap each actual data object in another lightweight object that acts as a facade, some people refer to this as having a viewmodel for each row's data object. For example here is a simple Customer object:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}

    public string Surname {get; set;}
}
```

As you store this in the ObservableCollection in your viewmodel you can wrap it:

```
public class CustomerWrapper
{
    private Customer _customer;
    public CustomerWrapper (Customer customer)
    {
        _customer = customer;
    }

    public bool HasRelation{get;set;}

    public Customer Customer { get {return _customer;}}
}
```

Now if you want to indicate an interdependency between your Customer objects, for example if they were part of a family, you can simply set the `HasRelation` property once the CustomerWrapper object has been created:

```
var myCustomerList = GetMyCustomers();
foreach (var customer in myCustomerList)
{
    myObservableCollection.Add(new CustomerWrapper(customer) 
    { 
        HasRelation = myCustomerList.Where(p => string.Equals(p.Surname, customer.Surname).Count() > 1) 
    }); 
}
```

Now when you bind your repeater control to the ObservableCollection you can use the HasRelation property to control UI color etc.

Keep in mind that I've kept this is a contrived example and I've kept it simple, I've deliberately missed some stuff out to keep it brief. If your viewmodel subscribes to the property changed event of each Customer object it can then update the CustomerWrapper objects as needed. The interdependency state doesn't need to be stored with the data in the repository because you can determine it each time you display the data. One of the things I ommitted was wrapping the FirstName and Surname proeprties - you could put in a wrapper property for them, or you can simply use the path in your XAML's binding to drill down to the nested object.

Comment: Curious! I derived my application from the Writer sample of the [WPF Application Framework](http://waf.codeplex.com/). In this case, the FlowDocument class that holds the data is part of the model, if I'm not totally mistaken. How can it be?

Comment: @thomiel That is simply an open source project that is hosted on CodePlex - hosting it there doesn't mean it is validated or endorsed in any way by anyone, especially Microsoft. Like I said above, you *can* store data in the model, but IMVHO and extensive experience you *shouldn't* - it leads to problems and smelly code in the long run. One problem you will face is that there are many interpretations of what the MVVM pattern is, and many people confuse it with aspects of MVC and MVP.

Comment: Bummer! WAF seemed like a nice tangible example to learn about the concept, though it's not purestrain M-V-VM. I really miss something like a m-v-vm.org, an arena where all those philosofters meet and discuss, creating RFC-like results... You don't btw. happen to have some URLs ready that lead me to the temples of high and hardcore MVVMing? I started with Laurent Bugnion and Josh Smith before getting stuck with WAF.